# Generate fonts for html editor

Tags: c#, jquery, .net

I have c# .net webbapp

And on it, here is a content editable area.  I want to create a drop down box and list a range of fonts for the user to select and use.

Are there any standard functions in .net that can be used to generate a list of available fonts to the user?

or is this something that can be done in jquery to look at the client and generate a drop down list from what they have available?

Comment: Javascript cannot detect what fonts the client machine has installed. It would be a much better idea to use a pre-chosen list of fonts from a CDN anyway, such as Google Fonts.

Comment: Thanks - which question is this is a duplicate of for me to look at please?

Comment: It's linked in the yellow box at the top of this page. Try refreshing your browser if you can't see it.